# 'Customize' button in admin bar for CSS

Tags: plugins, customization, themes, css, updates

On the WordPress.org site I'm an admin for, we have a `Customize` button in the Admin bar (see very left):
[image]

This allows us to easily edit CSS on the front end without editing any of our files. I specifically remember reading that this feature allows us to write CSS that won't be overwritten by a theme update.

Now the time to update has come, and I'd like to absolutely confirm this. But I can't find any references to this button online.

What's this feature called? Is it on everyone's WordPress.org site, or is this some special feature of our theme or perhaps a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WP Toolbar's *Customize* button will launch the Theme Customizer. This is standard on all WordPress sites, but it could be disabled via themes or plugins.

WordPress version 4.7 added the [*Custom CSS*](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/10/11/feature-proposal-better-theme-customizations-via-custom-css-with-live-previews/) feature which will allow you to add your own styles to the activated theme. These styles will not be overridden when updating the theme.

> ...custom CSS safely stays available through updating and switching
>   themes, starting fresh for each new theme.

Technically, it would be possible for a theme to stomp on any options or theme mods with an update, so you should always make a backup of your database and files before updating.